# Is there any printed or handwritten precursor to this 门 (door, gate) glyph?

Tags: characters, fonts, strokes

I recently started seeing this odd rendering of the 门 character, may be it's only in the font that my browser defaults to. Here's an image (2nd character in the title):

[image]

Does anyone know if this glyph is a valid variant or some modern "invention" of a font designer?

Comment: You've got a jap font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such handwriting in calligraphy works of Tang Yin (唐寅, also well known as 唐伯虎, Tang Bohu, 1470-1524, Ming Dynasty).

I found some pictures of his writing, 《落花诗册》.  I marked the related characters with a mark to the right. The genuine writing is now in Suzhou Museum, Jiangsu Province.

[image: 門]
[image: 開]
[image: 開 and 闌]
[image: 悶]

Comment: Oh, everybody knows Tang Bohu, _Three Smiles_ (with Ivy Ling-po) is one of my favorite films.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the written form of this character in some other regions. This is more likely to be a locale problem on your browser.

Chinese characters (a.k.a CJK unified ideographs in Unicode) are not only used in China. In different regions, the same characters can be written in different shapes. Fonts for Chinese character is those regions will reflect these differences. In other words, it is the same word, encoded the same way (in Unicode), but appears to be in different shapes in fonts designed for different regions. It is very likely the one you see is not a valid form accepted in China.

In order to fix this, in your browser content locale settings, you need to set Chinese Simplified (China) as a preferred language, and give it higher priority than other languages that also use Chinese characters. "Other languages" include but may not be limited to Japanese (Japan), Chinese Traditional (Hongkong), and Chinese Traditional (Taiwan). Like this in Chrome:

[image]

If you don't put Chinese Simplified there, or put some of those "other languages" above Chinese Simplified, you are likely to have such issues.

Answer (score 1):

it ought to be 门(U+95e8), the simplified of 門, somehow your browser used a japanese font for font substitution. if you manually change the display font, it should change back to 门.

i think that it's not a case of variant character.

[image: p1]

Answer (score 1):

This is a common 略字 (abbreviated character) used in Japan mostly for handwriting.